# Django Unit Test - IDs of created objects

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

**Sample models.py**

*models.py*

```
class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Food')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Suppose** that I have written unit test/s:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from myapp.models import Food

class TestWhateverFunctions(TestCase):
    """
    This class contains tests for whatever functions.
    """

    def setUp(self):
        """
        This method runs before the execution of each test case.
        """
        Food.objects.create(name='Pizza') # Will the created object have id of 1?
        Food.objects.create(name='Pasta') # Will the created object have id of 2?

    def test_if_food_is_pizza(self):
        """
        Test if the given food is pizza.
        """
        food = Food.objects.get(id=1)

        self.assertEqual(food.name, 'Pizza')

    def test_if_food_is_pasta(self):
        """
        Test if the given food is pasta.
        """
        food = Food.objects.get(id=2)

        self.assertEqual(food.name, 'Pasta')
```

I was wondering if it's safe to assume that the id's of the created objects in **setUp() method** will always start at `id 1` and so on and so forth? If not, is there a specific reason why if the test database is always **destroyed** after running all tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is *not* safe to assume that the ids will always start at 1 and increment. They may have higher ids if other tests have run beforehand and created `Food` rows, and unit tests are not executed in any guaranteed order.

Save references to the model instances on your test setup:

```
class TestWhateverFunctions(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.food1 = Food.objects.create(name='Pizza')
        self.food2 = Food.objects.create(name='Pasta')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your speedy reply. I figured as I've been seeing a lot of examples online wherein they assume the `objects' id`. Follow up question, why is it behaving this way when the test database is technically **destroyed** upon reaching the end of the test?

Comment: The test database is destroyed at the end of the test **session**.  The test session may execute many different test cases (usually within transactions, but still using the same test database).

Comment: Got it. That's what I'm missing the term **test session**. Thanks again for your help and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great example. For anyone as new as I am, I then used:

```
self.food1.id
```

as the primary key for testing a request and response of a URL.

Answer (score 0):

use this to get the first object , no need to pass the id value

comment = Food.objects.get()